# org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory was unintentionally initialized at build time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-native

I am using GraalVM 21, JDK 21, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

```
# On Ubuntu 22.04 Operating system (WSL 2)
chmod +x mvnw 
./mvnw -Pnative spring-boot:build-image
```

Log

```bash
[INFO]     [creator]      - '-H:+StaticExecutableWithDynamicLibC' (origin(s): command line)
[INFO]     [creator]      - '-H:ResourceConfigurationResources' (origin(s): 'META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/native-image.properties' in 'file:///workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar', 'META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/native-image.properties' in 'file:///workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.17.jar', 'META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/native-image.properties' in 'file:///workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.17.jar')
[INFO]     [creator]      - '-H:ReflectionConfigurationResources' (origin(s): 'META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/native-image.properties' in 'file:///workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar', 'META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/native-image.properties' in 'file:///workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.17.jar', 'META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/native-image.properties' in 'file:///workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.17.jar')
[INFO]     [creator]     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     [creator]     Build resources:
[INFO]     [creator]      - 8.49GB of memory (68.5% of 12.40GB system memory, determined at start)
[INFO]     [creator]      - 4 thread(s) (100.0% of 4 available processor(s), determined at start)
[INFO]     [creator]     Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
[INFO]     [creator]     Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
[INFO]     [creator]     SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
[INFO]     [creator]     SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
[INFO]     [creator]     SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
[INFO]     [creator]     [2/8] Performing analysis...  []                                (58.2s @ 1.13GB)
[INFO]     [creator]        10,656 reachable types   (85.8% of   12,415 total)
[INFO]     [creator]        16,663 reachable fields  (61.0% of   27,318 total)
[INFO]     [creator]        50,655 reachable methods (59.2% of   85,634 total)
[INFO]     [creator]         3,407 types,   314 fields, and 2,521 methods registered for reflection
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
[INFO]     [creator]      org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[INFO]     [creator]     org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService
[INFO]     [creator]     To see how the classes got initialized, use --trace-class-initialization=org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory,org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService
[INFO]     [creator]     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     [creator]         9.0s (12.6% of total time) in 99 GCs | Peak RSS: 2.49GB | CPU load: 3.71
[INFO]     [creator]     ================================================================================
[INFO]     [creator]     Finished generating '....MasterdataserviceApplication' in 1m 10s.
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to contribute native-image layer
[INFO]     [creator]     error running build
[INFO]     [creator]     exit status 1
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:35 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-08T16:10:40+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.1:build-image (default-cli) on project masterdataservice: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.1:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `[INFO]     [creator]     Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts
` well this is more or less the solution, right in there. Remove that jar, which is probably pulled in by some other transitive depedency (or maybe you decided to add it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Use solution at https://github.com/Consensys/teku/issues/7486#issuecomment-1720438947 , use log4j-over-slf4j dependency

Remove Apache Commons Bean Ultis (what used in feature Beans copy)